# How to parse a JSON object, update it in place and then save it back to disk in Java?

Tags: java, json

What is the easiest to use JSON Java library to parse a JSON (It's structure may vary so I can't mapp it to a Java class as I seen multiple libraries do it) update some elements in an array in this JSON and then save it back to disk?

There are so many libraries for JSON in Java (Gson, Jackson, etc.) and so complex that seem like a total overkill for what i need as opposed to other programming languages.

What's the most straightforward one to use? (that maybe also has a few examples on how to do this)

Comment: What do you mean "save it back"?  You can't, in general, update the middle of a file if you might be changing the length of the data -- you must update the entire file.  So your job is to simply parse the JSON, update the parsed image, serialize the parsed image back to a byte string, and write that back to disk.

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant.

Comment: Go to json.org.  There are at least 20 different JSON packages listed for Java.  IMO, GSON and Jackson make it over-complicated (but then so does Java, with their ill-conceived "generic" implementation).

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success with `Json-Simple`.

You can check it out [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).

I used it to parse 1.5 Million Twitter Streaming data (which is in JSON).

You may find some sample code here on my [blog](http://www.mrgeek.me/technology/datascience/data-mining-1-5-million-tweets-for-twitter-sentiment-analysis/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java-json` jar. The docs for this jar can be found [here](http://www.json.org/java/)

Answer (score 1):

I use [net.sf.json](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/package-summary.html) to do this.

here is an example :

```
    String fromFile="{\"he\",\"hello\"}" //read from file instead
    JSONObject object=(JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJSON( fromFile );
    object.put("he", "hello2");
    System.out.println(object);
```

output:

```
{"he":"hello2"}
```